# IndexOutOfBoundsException when making one Arraylist equal to another

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I am trying to filter my RecyclerView using SearchView by following this guide: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/searchview-in-android-with-recyclerview/

However, I am getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException when making one Arraylist equal to another, which I believe is happening at this portion of the code here:

```java
public void filterList(ArrayList filteredlist) {
    // below line is to add our filtered
    // list in our course array list.
    book_title = filteredlist;
    // below line is to notify our adapter
    // as change in recycler view data.
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Here is the full code for my adapter class:**

```
package com.benjamin.kwok.recipertracker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList book_id, book_title, book_author, book_pages;

    CustomAdapter(Activity activity, Context context, ArrayList book_id, ArrayList book_title, ArrayList book_author,
                  ArrayList book_pages){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = context;
        this.book_id = book_id;
        this.book_title = book_title;
        this.book_author = book_author;
        this.book_pages = book_pages;
    }

    public void filterList(ArrayList filteredlist) {
        // below line is to add our filtered
        // list in our course array list.
        book_title = filteredlist;
        // below line is to notify our adapter
        // as change in recycler view data.
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.book_title_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_title.get(position)));
        holder.book_author_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_author.get(position)));
        holder.book_pages_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_pages.get(position)));
        //Recyclerview onClickListener
        holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(book_id.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("title", String.valueOf(book_title.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("author", String.valueOf(book_author.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("pages", String.valueOf(book_pages.get(position)));
                activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return book_id.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView book_id_txt, book_title_txt, book_author_txt, book_pages_txt;
        LinearLayout mainLayout;

        MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            book_title_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_title_txt);
            book_author_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_description_txt);
            book_pages_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_pages_txt);
            mainLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
            //Animate Recyclerview
            Animation translate_anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.translate_anim);
            mainLayout.setAnimation(translate_anim);
        }

    }

}
```

**And the full code for my MainActivity:**

```
package com.benjamin.kwok.recipertracker;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FloatingActionButton add_button;
    FloatingActionButton camera_button;
    ImageView empty_imageview;
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView no_data;
    MyDatabaseHelper myDB;
    ArrayList<String> recipe_id, recipe_title, recipe_description, recipe_minutes;
    CustomAdapter customAdapter;
    final static private int NEW_PICTURE = 1;
    private String mCameraFileName;

    private static final String TAG = "CapturePicture";
    static final int REQUEST_PICTURE_CAPTURE = 1;

    private String pictureFilePath;

    private String deviceIdentifier;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);

//        SharedPreferences mSharedPreference= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
//        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreference.edit();
//        String text= mSharedPreference.getString(getString(R.string.name), "");
////        name_output.setText(text);


        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        add_button = findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        camera_button = findViewById(R.id.camera_button);
        empty_imageview = findViewById(R.id.empty_imageview);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        no_data = findViewById(R.id.no_data);
        add_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        camera_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 100);

            }
        });


        myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
        recipe_id = new ArrayList<>();
        recipe_title = new ArrayList<>(10);
        recipe_description = new ArrayList<>();
        recipe_minutes = new ArrayList<>();

        storeDataInArrays();

        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,this, recipe_id, recipe_title, recipe_description,
                recipe_minutes);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

        loadData();
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 100) {

            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap captureImage = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(captureImage);

            saveToGallery();

        }
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image added to Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

    }

    private void saveToGallery(){


        BitmapDrawable draw = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = draw.getBitmap();

        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/RecipeImages");
        dir.mkdirs();
        String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
        File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { outFile.getPath() }, new String[] { "image/jpeg" }, null);

        try {
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
        try {
            outStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            outStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    void storeDataInArrays(){
        Cursor cursor = myDB.readAllData();
        if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
            empty_imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            no_data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                recipe_id.add(cursor.getString(0));
                recipe_title.add(cursor.getString(1));
                recipe_description.add(cursor.getString(2));
                recipe_minutes.add(cursor.getString(3));
            }
            empty_imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            no_data.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    public void loadData() {
        SharedPreferences mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String name = mPreferences.getString("name","");
        setTitle(name+"'s" + " Recipe Tracker");

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
//        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.actionSearch);

        // getting search view of our item.
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        // below line is to call set on query text listener method.
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                // inside on query text change method we are
                // calling a method to filter our recycler view.
                filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    private void filter(String text) {
        // creating a new array list to filter our data.
        ArrayList filteredlist = new ArrayList<>();

        // running a for loop to compare elements.
        for (String item : recipe_title) {
            // checking if the entered string matched with any item of our recycler view.
            if (item.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                // if the item is matched we are
                // adding it to our filtered list.
                filteredlist.add(item);
            }
        }
        if (filteredlist.isEmpty()) {
            // if no item is added in filtered list we are
            // displaying a toast message as no data found.
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Data Found..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // at last we are passing that filtered
            // list to our adapter class.
            customAdapter.filterList(filteredlist);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.delete_all){
            confirmDialog();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    void confirmDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Delete All?");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete all Data?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                MyDatabaseHelper myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                myDB.deleteAllData();
                //Refresh Activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

As soon as I start typing in a new search query, this error seems to get thrown.

Comment: Because `book_title` size is less then `book_id` ArrayList

Comment: Please add stack trace and add a comment on the line where the exception is thrown.